# Do not move binded circles when using OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier

Tags: javascript, google-maps, markerspiderfier

I decided to use [OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier) when having multiple markers on the same place or very close each other.

The problem was that in my scope each marker has binded marker which move when spiderfy is triggered.

Comment: I have also filled a [bug report](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/issues/110).

Answer (score 0):

Basically the solution is to add listeners and manualy ensure that the circles are kept in places.

```
this.oms.addListener('spiderfy', function (activeMarkers) {
    activeMarkers.forEach(function(marker) {
        console.log(marker._originalPosition);
        marker._circle.unbind('center');
        marker._circle.setCenter(marker._originalPosition);
    });
});
this.oms.addListener('unspiderfy', function (activeMarkers) {
    activeMarkers.forEach(function(marker) {
        circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
    });
});
```

Where you have to store `_originalPosition` in advance as original location is not available from the `_omsData` (see the [issue](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/issues/26)).